# Rollback Not Works Sometimes

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, rollback

we have hard coded actions on our projects. One of it creates an order and too many things integrated with that order. We are using just one `Commit()`. If everythings fine and there isn't any SQL exceptions, we save data correctly. If errors or deadlock happen from SQL we do rollback. But sometimes rollback not rolls everything back and saves some data or saving with missed data. Is it possible? If answer is yes how can i handle? Here is a part of code.

```
{
            var xorder = _Order.GetById(order.ID);
            ...
            if (completed)
            {
                ...
                _StockSummary.Get(...).ToList().ForEach(k => { _StockSummary.Delete(k); });
                _OrderSummary.Get(...).ToList().ForEach(k => { _OrderSummary.Delete(k); });
                _Conns.Get(...).ToList().ForEach(k => _Conns.Delete(k));
                order.StockSummaries.ForEach(item =>
                {
                    order.Lines.Where(...).ToList().ForEach(k =>
                    {
                        _Conns.Insert(new Conn()
                        {
                            ...
                        });
                    });
                    _StockSummary.Insert(item);
                });
                
                order.Lines.ForEach(item =>
                {
                    
                    _LineTran.Get(t => t.LineID == item.ID && !trans.Any(x => x == t.ID)).ToList().ForEach(t =>
                    {
                        _LineTran.Delete(t);
                    });
                    item.Transactions.ForEach(t =>
                    {
                        ...
                        if (...)
                            _LineTran.Update(t);
                    });
                    
                    if (item.ID == 0)
                    {
                        ...
                        _OrderLine.Insert(item);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ...
                        _OrderLine.Update(item);
                    }
                    ino++;
                });
                int on = 1;
                order.Summaries.ForEach(item =>
                {
                   ...
                    _OrderSummary.Insert(item);
                });
                _OrderLine.Get(k => k.OrderID == order.ID).ToList().ForEach(k =>
                {
                    if (k.Action == -1)
                    {
                        (...).ForEach(t => _LineTran.Delete(t));
                        _OrderLine.Delete(k);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _LineTran.Get(...).ToList().ForEach(t =>
                        {
                            if (...)
                                _LineTran.Delete(t);
                            else
                            {
                               ...
                                _LineTran.Update(t);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                var receipt = _Receipt.GetById(...);
                if (receipt != null)
                {
                    if (...)
                    {
                        _Receipt.Delete(receipt);
                        ...
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (...)
                        {
                            ...
                            if (...)
                            {
                                var opr = _Receipt.Get(...).ToList();
                                if (opr.Count() > 0)
                                {
                                    opr.ForEach(f =>
                                    {
                                       ...
                                        if (...)
                                        {
                                            ...
                                            _CustomerTransaction.Update(trans);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                            ...
                        }
                        ...
                        _Receipt.Update(receipt);
                        ...
                    }
                }
                else if (...)
                {
                    if (xorder != null)
                    {
                        ...
                        var rDelete = _Receipt.Get(...).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (rDelete != null)
                        {
                            _Receipt.Delete(rDelete);
                        }
                    }
                    var Receipt = new Receipt();
                    ...
                    order.Receipt = Receipt;
                    _Receipt.Insert(Receipt);
                }

                if (order.ID == 0)
                {
                    _Log.Insert(new OrderProcessLog()
                    {
                        ...
                    });
                    ...
                    _Order.Insert(order);
                }
                else
                {
                    _Log.Insert(new OrderProcessLog()
                    {
                        ...
                    });
                    
                    if (...)
                    {
                        _detail.Get(...).ToList().ForEach(f =>
                        {
                            _detail.Delete(f);
                        });
                    }
                    _Order.Update(order);
                    
                }
                try
                {
                    Unitofwork.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Unitofwork.Rollback();
                    throw new Exception(e.Message);
                }
                if (CalcOnSave == true)
                    Calc(order.ID); // This one has sql commands too on action.
                if (CalcProcessTime == true)
                    CalcProcessTimes(order.ID);  // This one has sql commands too on action.
                try
                {
                    _Order.UpdateOrderStatus(order.ID);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return Json("success", 0);
                }
                return Json("success", 0);

            }
            ...
        }
```

Comment: "sometimes rollback not rolls everything back" - Nope! You have bugs in your code.

Comment: You're showing us code with lots of omissions, so we have *no* chance of running this code and there's very little chance that you've *verified* that the statements you've left in would actually recreate the problem. We need a [mcve]

Comment: there is some `update` function in your code that we can't see whats those contain, I'm 99% sure those function got something to mess with db, hence @MitchWheat words of wisdom : "you have bug in your code".

Comment: I get it, I need to show more content. Can't do it without ask my manager. Thanks for help.